# Postgres jsonb update object in arbitrary nesting

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, sql-update

I have a table column in Postgres which is a jsonb. This column contains jsons of arbitrary levels of nesting. In these nestings I am trying to find all the object which carry a specific property ("key_a"="foo") and once I find them I want to replace the entire object with another object - which is based on the former one. For example, let's assume that the original object looks like so:

```json
[
   {
      "a":{
         "b": {
         },
         "c": {
         },
         "d": {
          "key_a":"foo"
         }
      }
   }
]
```

The object above satisfies our search criteria ("key_a"="foo"), thus we want to update it. The update should look like so

```json
[
   {
      "a":{
         "b": {
         },
         "c": {
         },
         "d": {
            "or":[
              "key_a":"foo",
              "key_a":"bar",
              "key_a":"bla"
            ]
         }
       }
   }
   
]
```

My approach is to:

1. First find the json path that needs to updated using `json_path_query` - since the object that satisfies the search criteria might be arbitrarily deep in the jsonb
2. Use this path in combination with `jsonb_set` to update the original structure.

Unfortunately I'm far from even completing the first step.

I cannot find any SQL function which provides the json path. The closest I have found is the following:

```sql
SELECT  myt.id,jsonb_path_query(
            myt.query,
            '$.** ? (@.key_a == "foo")'
        ) -> 'value'
FROM   (
        -- Query which returns the distinct ids of the jsons which contain the specific key
     
) as myt
```

Nevertheless, not even this produces correct results since:

- It does return the objects which the specified key BUT
- It returns multiple entries, meaning that if the json has only one occurrence of the specified key in one of each objects then the query produces more than one rows.

Not sure even if the original approach is correct here.

How would you go about such an update?

Comment: I don't think that is possible.

Comment: The JSON example you show is not valid, It needs to be `[ { "a":{ ... {"key_a":"foo"}}}]`

Comment: I can't explain it since I have to get to bed to get up in a couple of hours, but you can use recursion for this:  https://dbfiddle.uk/EDP1Vz7l The `p` column holds the path to the parent that you can pass to `jsonb_set()`

Comment: I cleaned up the `coalesce()` in this version:  https://dbfiddle.uk/Ci0GiR4Z

Comment: Thanks for your response @MikeOrganek. I think that this is the solution to the first part of the problem right? Your query produces the json path of the objects which carry the desired key/value pair

Comment: Yes.  That gets you the paths to the keys.  As I said, the `p` column can be the first argument to your call to `jsonb_set()`.  If you have to replace more than one key in the same document, I believe you will need to recurse again to do repeated updates in place.  I suggest you look into PL/PGSQL, instead.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe maybe you're right and it's not really possible. I gave it an entire day of effort and then ended up doing the migration on an application level.